# Localization is returning null. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: android, android-location

```
double longitude = 0;
double latitude = 0;


try {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();

} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this code, the latitude and longitude is returning null.I want to get location without using internet.

Comment: have you enabled GPS in your device ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. longitude and latitud is returning 0.

Comment: Are you trying in side the office room because GPS_PROVIDER requires open sky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There nothing wrong with your code, You are using GPS_PROVIDER which requires open sky field to fetch GPS Information. I suggest you to use NETWORK_PROVIDER if you want to fetch GPS details in side the room as well.

```
try 
{
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();

} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But I want to get location without use the internet. I dont want to connect the internet to get location. That's why I using GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: in that case you must go out side in open sky field or near the window to fetch lat-long information.

Comment: So , if I understand, if I using NETWORK_PROVIDER, I have to connect to the internet. And if I want to use GPS_PROVIDER I have to go to a fied or something like that.

Comment: @Roland, don't know what you mean with a field (big or small). but a little open space, so just no "roof" above your head should do it already. But yes, it is true what you said.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is: my users will use app and at the some point, it will get their localization. I want it to get location even without the internet. Then when the user get a connection, it will save the data in a server.